# POST doesn't create object in Java

Tags: java, rest, post

I am trying to develop a RESTful application that allows the client to add users to a database. This is the User class

```
public class User {

private String id;
private String name;

public User(String id, String name){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

//------------Getters and setters-----------------------------------------------------
public String getId(){
    return id;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}
}
```

this is the User database class

```
public class UserDatabase {

private Map<String, String> users = new HashMap<String, String>();

public UserDatabase(){
    users.put("2", "User2");
    users.put("3", "User3");
}

public Map<String, String> getAllUsers(){
    return users;
}

public String getUserName(String id){
    return users.get(id);
}

public void addUser(String id, String name){
    users.put(id, name);
}
}
```

this is the User resource

```
@Path("/users")
public class UserResource {

UserDatabase usersDatabase = new UserDatabase();

@GET
@Path("/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)  
public String getUser(@PathParam("id") String id){
    String response = String.valueOf(usersDatabase.getAllUsers().size());
    return response + " " + usersDatabase.getUserName(id);
}

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addUser(String userString) throws JSONException { 
    JSONObject user = new JSONObject(userString);
    String userId = user.getString("id");
    String userName = user.getString("name");
    usersDatabase.addUser(userId, userName);
    String result = "Created user with id: " + userId + " and name: " + usersDatabase.getUserName(userId);
    return Response.status(201).entity(result).build(); 
}

}
```

And this is the client with which i make a POST request to add a new user and then a GET request to get the user i just added

```
public class TestClient {

private final String baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/BoardGameManager/rest";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{ 

    TestClient client = new TestClient();       
    client.sendPostRequest("/users");
    client.sendGetRequest("/users/1");
}

private void sendGetRequest(String urlString) throws IOException{

    //Building and sending GET request
    URL url = new URL(baseUrl+ urlString);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();  
    System.out.println("Sending get request : "+ url);  
    System.out.println("Response code : "+ responseCode);

    //Reading response from input Stream
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));  
    String output;  
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();    
    while ((output = in.readLine()) != null){  
        response.append(output);  
    }  
    in.close();  

    //printing result from response  
    System.out.println(response.toString());
}

private void sendPostRequest(String urlString) throws IOException {  

    //Building POST request
    URL url = new URL(baseUrl + urlString);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
    String postData = "{\"id\": \"1\",\"name\": \"User1\"}";

    //Sending POST request
    connection.setDoOutput(true);  
    DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    outputStream.writeBytes(postData);  
    outputStream.flush();  
    outputStream.close();

    //Receiving response
    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();  
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);  
    System.out.println("Post Data : " + postData);  
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    String output;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    while ((output = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(output);
    }
    in.close();

    //printing result from response
    System.out.println(response.toString());

}

}
```

The problem is that when i make the POST request the user is added, but when I try to get it with the GET request the user i just added doesn't exist, and I can't understand why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are instantiating `userDatabases` as `new UserDatabase()` so everytime you get a new copy of `userDatabases` hence you get everytime a new `users Map`.

I propose to make your `UserDatabase`a singleton instead to keep every new added  user to the Map:

```
public class UserDatabase {

    private static UserDatabase instance = null;

    public static UserDatabase getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new UserDatabase();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    private UserDatabase(){
        users.put("2", "User2");
        users.put("3", "User3");
    }

    //....

}
```

Then instantiate `UserDatabase` like this :

```
@Path("/users")
public class UserResource {

    UserDatabase usersDatabase = UserDatabase.getInstance();

}
```

Now everytime you call `UserDatabase.getInstance()` you will get the same copy of it hence the same `users Map`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I modified the code as you said, but now the POST gives me an error, when trying to add a new user. Is it fine if UserDatabase contains the map (initialized in the constructor) along with the instance field?

Comment: i think you have to keep : private Map<String, String> users = new HashMap<String, String>();

Comment: What is the problem you have ?

Comment: In this way POST and GET don't work, even if i only do a GET to obtain a user i add in the constructor of the UserDatabase it returns an error

Comment: It says that the server returned error code 500, but i think that the problem is that usersDatabase is not initialized even though it should be (that's why POST and GET don't work anymore)

Comment: Sorry my mistake :p i updated the post, it  should be if(instance == null) not if(instance != null)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't even have to implement singleton pattern here if you are using spring boot to develop your micro service. You can use `@Service` annotation on your  `UserDatabase`  class. Then in your `UserResource` class do the following.

```
@Autowired
UserDatabase usersDatabase = new UserDatabase();
```

Spring will manage singleton instances here on behalf of you.

Following dependencies would be enough. But I reckon you to create a project using [spring initializer](http://start.spring.io/) by adding dependencies as needed. The default dependencies as given below would be sufficient as I remember. Additionally you may find a [sample project here](https://github.com/ravindraranwala/SpringBootRxJava).

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thanks, which jar I have to use to be able to use the @Autowired annotation?